# Neo4j TestGraphDatabase: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to get neo4j unit tests working, as per [the documentation here.](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html)

I've copied the code exactly (bar the assert statements, which I removed).

I'm using the same Maven dependencies, except I'm using version `2.2.3`.

When I run the tests, I get this stack trace:

```
2016-04-14 02:23:25.832+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Lifecycle exception Failed to transition component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle@6f4adfd6' from STOPPED to SHUTTING_DOWN. Please see attached cause exception
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to transition component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle@6f4adfd6' from STOPPED to SHUTTING_DOWN. Please see attached cause exception
<snip>
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:
    neostore.counts.db.a (1 mapping)
    neostore (1 mapping)
    neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db (1 mapping)
    neostore.schemastore.db (1 mapping)
    neostore.nodestore.db (1 mapping)
    neostore.nodestore.db.labels (1 mapping)
    neostore.relationshipstore.db (1 mapping)
    neostore.propertystore.db (1 mapping)
    neostore.propertystore.db.arrays (1 mapping)
    neostore.propertystore.db.strings (1 mapping)
    neostore.propertystore.db.index (1 mapping)
    neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys (1 mapping)
    neostore.labeltokenstore.db (1 mapping)
    neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names (1 mapping)
    neostore.relationshiptypestore.db (1 mapping)
    neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names (1 mapping)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.close(MuninnPageCache.java:483)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle.shutdown(PageCacheLifecycle.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:555)
    ... 27 more
```

I've tried upgrading to version `2.3.3`, but then I get a different error:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@5c86c46a' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:102)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/kernel/logging/Logging
```

[According to Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel/1.8/org/neo4j/kernel/logging/Logging.java) would make sense, `org.neo4j.kernel.logging.Logging` only exists up to version `2.2.3`.

What's the likely issue here? - It's a dependency incompatibility issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I had `spring-data-neo4j 3.4.0.RELEASE` as an unused dependency, and this was causing issues. Removed it and it works, using neo4j `2.3.3`.